# Free memory from a long vector

Tags: c++, stl, vector, memory-management

What I wanted to do is to release the memory used by a `vector` (say `vector<vector<int>>`) and I used the swap trick, i.e., `v.swap(vector<vector<int>>())`.

However, what I observed that the swap trick work well for short vectors but NOT for long ones, for example I tried one vector of length 10,000,000, which took 1.4G in memory, after the swap there is still 1.0G not released.

Below is the code I used for testing.

Thanks advance for any idea!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

typedef unsigned long long     int64;

int main()
{
    {
        vector<vector<int64>> batch;
        {
            vector<int64> v;
            for (size_t i = 0; i < 12; ++i)
                v.push_back(8000000000);
            for (size_t i = 0; i < 10000000; ++i)
                batch.push_back(v);
        }
        cout << "pause 1" << endl;
        cin.ignore();
        {
            vector<vector<int64>> tmp;
            batch.swap(tmp);
            // I tried several things here.
            //tmp.swap(batch);
            //batch.clear();
            //batch.shrink_to_fit();
            //batch = tmp;
        }
        cout << "pause 2" << endl;
        cin.ignore();
    }
    cout << "pause 3" << endl;
    cin.ignore();
}
```

Comment: How are you measuring "memory usage"?  Freeing memory in your program does not necessarily mean that the runtime returns the memory back to the OS (or that the OS reclaims it).

Comment: It's possible that the operating system caches your memory allocations. Memory allocations are expensive, so the operating system may "figure" that since your program is going to repeatedly allocate huge chunks of memory, it's not going to mark them as free.

Comment: Which operating system?  Which compiler?  Operating systems (and compilers, and runtimes, ...) routinely have different memory allocation rules for big allocations than for small ones.

Comment: I use G++4.6 in Ubuntu 10.04, the memory usage measure I used is the number displayed in "top".

Comment: If the reason is that OS does caching, is it possible to disable the caching?

Comment: Another observation is that if the vector has 1000 elements each of which has 120000 integers, (it takes the same amount of memory), the de-allocation works fine. But not for the 10,000,000x12 vector.

Comment: I don't think it's the OS's fault, it's the C++ runtime system. But why would you want to disable it? If the memory isn't accessed anymore and other applications need more, it will be swapped out and do no harm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

James, In silico, and Max all are correct with their remarks. You expect memory to be freed when you call `batch.swap(tmp)`, since `tmp` is empty. I just ran your program on 64 bit Linux, compiled using gcc 4.6.0. When observing the memory consumption with top, it goes 2 GB -> 1.8 GB -> 1.8 GB. However, when adding a `batch2` and filling it after `pause 2` just like `batch` was filled, memory consumption doesn't increase. Running a version where `batch.swap(tmp)` is commented out, thus actually having two huge vectors, the memory consumption goes 2 GB -> 3.2 GB -> 2.8 GB -> 2.8 GB.

Here's the complete code with command line option added:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

typedef unsigned long long     int64;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    bool no_swap = (argc > 1 && strcmp(argv[1], "-noswap") == 0); 
    {
        vector<vector<int64> > batch;
        vector<vector<int64> > batch2;
        {
            vector<int64> v;
            for (size_t i = 0; i < 12; ++i)
                v.push_back(8000000000);
            for (size_t i = 0; i < 10000000; ++i)
                batch.push_back(v);
        }
        cout << "pause 1" << endl;
        cin.ignore();
        {
            vector<vector<int64> > tmp;
            if (no_swap) {
                cout << "NOT calling batch.swap(tmp)" << endl;
            } else {                    
                cout << "calling batch.swap(tmp)" << endl;
                batch.swap(tmp);
            }
        }
        cout << "pause 2" << endl;
        cin.ignore();
        {
            vector<int64> v2;
            for (size_t i = 0; i < 12; ++i)
                v2.push_back(8000000000);
            for (size_t i = 0; i < 10000000; ++i)
                batch2.push_back(v2);
        }
        cout << "pause 3" << endl;
        cin.ignore();
    }
    cout << "pause 4" << endl;
    cin.ignore();
}
```

Some explanation of this behavior can be found [here](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/faq.html#faq.reports) and [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/bk01pt04ch11.html). From the latter:

> In use, allocator may allocate and deallocate using implementation-specified strategies 
>   and heuristics. Because of this, every call to an allocator object's allocate member 
>   function may not actually call the global operator new. This situation is also 
>   duplicated for calls to the deallocate member function.

According to this document, caching can be disabled by setting `GLIBCXX_FORCE_NEW`, but this doesn't work for me ...

Comment: Is it possible to disable the caching? What I wanted to do is to free the memory used by one process, so that another process which uses big memory can be started. If we can allow the un-release memory to be used by another process, that would also be fine.

Comment: @Larry: When there's another process that needs the memory now, the operating system will be smart enough to provide it to that process whenever they are not used. Even if they are being "held" on by caching algorithms.

Comment: @In silico The OS doesn't know that the memory isn't needed any more by the first process. All it can do is swap out the unused memory. Normally this works just fine, but I can see that in this case the disk I/O involved could be avoided.

Comment: @ahans: That depends on how the C++ runtime was implemented. It may be possible that the C++ runtime is smart enough to tell the OS that certain blocks of memory isn't actually being used. I know under Windows 7 the OS makes a distinction between "Standby" and "Free" memory, both of which can be used to satisfy the memory needs of any process.

Comment: @In silico I don't know about Windows, but I'm pretty sure that userspace applications in Linux allocate memory using the `brk` system call. As far as I know there's no way of telling the OS that a certain memory area might be used again later, all you can do is change the data segment size, which essentially means allocating or deallocating memory.

Comment: @ahans: Ah, okay then. Apparently this is a C++ runtime issue as opposed to an OS issue.

Answer (score 1):

What's likely is that your CRT implementation decided that it really would be a better idea not to give that memory back to the operating system just yet in case you want another 12 80MB contiguous allocations.